# Refresh values when application enters foreground

Tags: iphone, ios, alassetslibrary

My application is using 'ALAssetsGroup' to keep track of the users albums

and i display these albums in my application
the user can click on the albums and see the images as well.

Now the problem arises when the user downloads images through safari or he alters the albums in any way .

my application still holds reference to the old albums instead of the new one
so i tried to refresh the albums using the

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

but the albums still seem to have the old value,
if i refresh them once more 'within' the application they get the correct values.

is there something else i can use to resolve this issue .. ?
maybe a notification .. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        //This Registers a Notification for any changes
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(didChangeLibrary:) 
                                                 name:ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification 
                                               object:[AGImagePickerController defaultAssetsLibrary]];

- (void)didChangeLibrary:(NSNotification *)notification
{
        //Enter some code here to deal with the album changing
}
```

Edit: It seems like this does not work on iOS 5 (A radar has been opened for Apple, because this is a bug).

Here is a work around to use in the meantime:

> Call

```
[self.assetsLibrary writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:nil metadata:nil
 completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) { }];
```

> immediately after creating instance of ALAssetsLibrary Observe
>   ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification (not
>   NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `applicationDidBecomeActive` method in the ApplicationDelegate

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
     */
}
```